# Combine different length rows in one in R

Tags: r, dataframe, bind

Imagine I have the following results:

```
>coef(model1)
                   Estimate  Std. Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
    X1           -1.3006813 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
    X2          -12.1455641 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02
    X3           11.0701123 9.367725395  1.1817290 2.381590e-01
    X4            3.2903167 0.690324322  4.7663346 2.810855e-06
    X5            0.0240804 0.005345124  4.5051151 9.201743e-06
    X6            0.1834814 0.047485944  3.8639097 1.341940e-04
```

and

```
>coef(model2)
                       Estimate  Std. Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
        X1           -1.3180103 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
        X2          -10.5006410 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02
```

and

```
>coef(model6)
                           Estimate  Std. Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
            X2           -1.3256782 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
            X6          -1.56931410 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02
```

What I want to do is to create this table, where each row is the coefficients of each model:

```
 X1      X2    X3      X4     X5     X6
-1.300 -12.145 11.070 3.290  0.0240 0.183
-1.318 -10.500
       -1.325                      -1.569
```

Any suggestions?
*Ideally, I would like to add an `* if p-value>0.05, ** if p-value>0.01 and *** if <0.01` so that it would be instantly added to latex with `library(xtable)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could get more concise, but as a start you might use this. Also, I used rounding so `-1.3006813` becomes `-1.301` in my code, not `1.300`. Also, please note `Pr...t..` is just the column name `Pr(>|t|)` badly read in.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

myfunction <- function(x){
  x %>% 
mutate(Std. = round(Std., 3),
       Std.Adjusted = ifelse(Pr...t.. > 0.05, paste0(Std., "*"), ifelse(Pr...t.. < 0.05 & Pr...t.. > 0.01, paste0(Std., "**"), paste0(Std., "***")))) %>% 
  select(Estimate, Std.Adjusted) %>% 
  spread(Estimate, Std.Adjusted)
}

rbind.fill(lapply(list(mod1,mod2,mod6), myfunction))

       X1        X2     X3      X4       X5       X6
1 -1.301* -12.146** 11.07* 3.29*** 0.024*** 0.183***
2 -1.318* -10.501**   <NA>    <NA>     <NA>     <NA>
3    <NA>   -1.326*   <NA>    <NA>     <NA> -1.569**
```

## DATA:

```
mod1 <- read.table(text = "
Estimate  Std. Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
X1           -1.3006813 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
X2          -12.1455641 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02
X3           11.0701123 9.367725395  1.1817290 2.381590e-01
X4            3.2903167 0.690324322  4.7663346 2.810855e-06
X5            0.0240804 0.005345124  4.5051151 9.201743e-06
X6            0.1834814 0.047485944  3.8639097 1.341940e-04
", h = T)


mod2 <- read.table(text = "
Estimate  Std. Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
X1           -1.3180103 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
X2          -10.5006410 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02
", h = T)

mod6 <- read.table(text = "
Estimate  Std. Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
X2           -1.3256782 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
X6          -1.56931410 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02  
", h = T)
```

Comment: I get this error: `Error: is.data.frame(.data) || is.list(.data) || is.environment(.data) is not TRUE` ... Could this be because i get my data from this: `coef(model1)` which has `names(coef(model1))` return `NULL` ? Note: `model1<-summary(lm....)`

Comment: probably due to the nature you read the data; `read.table` could allow for this; because it runs perfectly when i re-read my data with the `read.table` command..

Comment: I don't know how you made up model1.  You should be able however to store its coefficients as a dataframe, so you don't read.table() to read in your data.

Comment: if you run a model like lm and the take the `coef(summary(lm(Y~X)))` then i get that issue!

Comment: just do something like `df1 <- as.data.frame(coef(summary(lm(mpg ~ qsec + drat, mtcars))))`

Comment: This doesn't work for `summary.plm` (which happens to be my case) but in general yes!

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- list(model1, model2, model6)

data %>% 
  map_df(rownames_to_column, "Var", .id = 'Model') %>%
  select(Model, Var, Estimate) %>%
  spread(Var, Estimate)

|Model |        X1|         X2|       X3|       X4|        X5|         X6|
|:-----|---------:|----------:|--------:|--------:|---------:|----------:|
|1     | -1.300681| -12.145564| 11.07011| 3.290317| 0.0240804|  0.1834814|
|2     | -1.318010| -10.500641|       NA|       NA|        NA|         NA|
|3     |        NA|  -1.325678|       NA|       NA|        NA| -1.5693141|
```

Data:

```
model1 <- read.table(text = "
Estimate  Std.Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
X1           -1.3006813 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
X2          -12.1455641 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02
X3           11.0701123 9.367725395  1.1817290 2.381590e-01
X4            3.2903167 0.690324322  4.7663346 2.810855e-06
X5            0.0240804 0.005345124  4.5051151 9.201743e-06
X6            0.1834814 0.047485944  3.8639097 1.341940e-04
", h = T)


model2 <- read.table(text = "
Estimate  Std.Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
X1           -1.3180103 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
X2          -10.5006410 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02
", h = T)

model6 <- read.table(text = "
Estimate  Std.Error    t-value     Pr(>|t|)
X2           -1.3256782 1.962377480 -0.6628089 5.079128e-01
X6          -1.56931410 5.838937045 -2.0800985 3.828320e-02  
", h = T)
```

Not quite sure what you mean by the stars bit, but they could be added with a case_when statement in the pipe

Comment: Hi, when i run it i get this error: `Error: is.data.frame(df) is not TRUE` when i run `data %>% 
  map_df(rownames_to_column, "Var", .id = 'Model') %>%
  select(Model, Var, Estimate) %>%
  spread(Var, Estimate)`

Comment: hmmm, I think the error is due to the nature of the data? What i mean: my table is derived from this: `coef(model1)`. As a result it does't have column names; `names(coef(model1))` returns `Null`.

Comment: try something like this to get a the coefs into a nice format:  `library(broom); tidy(lm(formula = mpg ~ wt, data = mtcars))`